# Size of an Object Based on Distance

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say that an object is 1.8m tall at a distance of 0m. I am trying to work out the height of the object if it was 10m away. Is there an easy solution to this problem that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this surprisingly interesting question is that there  really is no answer without some context.

First note that the object is still $1.8$m tall, wherever it is. You are  asking how tall it *appears to be*  at $10$m. That can only be expressed as a relationship with its appearance at some other distance and the relationship is proportionality. . For example, it will appear to be half as tall at $10$m as it appears to be at $5$m and twice as tall as at $20$m.

Your use of "tall" and "height" rather than "long" and your curiosity about $1.8$m suggests that you are asking how tall a person $1.8$m person will seem to be at a distance of $10$m. The answer depends on your mental picture of how tall that person appears to you at some "usual" distance. Then you scale proportionally.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. My mistake, I did mean to say the apparent height of the object (which was in this case a person, I should have been a bit more specific). I never thought that the scale would be directly in proportion to the distance, thank you.